# Why was I unable to edit the question, but the edit got recorded?

Tags: support, questions, edits

I just wanted to edit a body of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181198/1839439) and to my surprise I received an error saying that a question with this title already exists (I guess I also added `?` in the title which made it the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2813871/1839439)). I then proceeded to try again, and this time I was able to save the question, but there seems to have been some glitch in the matrix and my edit was changed.

Here is what the question looked like before I edited it.

[image]

And here is what my edit looks like:
[image]

Maybe I am going crazy, but I clearly see `hey` at the start of the post, which I remember removing in my edit. Could someone please explain to me what am I missing? What happened to my edit?

Here is the web archive record to support my screenshot. http://web.archive.org/web/20190223234515/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password

Comment: OK, my first idea was that OP edited within the grace period and their edit is not in the history...but that's a post from close to a decade ago, so it's not that.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/144883

Comment: So, let me get this straight, even if my edit is rejected, the auto-magical removal of greetings is still executed on such posts? That is slightly confusing.

Comment: Well, I would argue that it is a good thing that such scripts get triggered even when the edit didn't went through. It looks strange at first, yes, but it does no harm in my opinion.